# How to check whether StringB starts with StringA in PHP?

Tags: php, string, substring, match

How can you check whether `StringB` **starts** with `StringA` ***if the length of both is variable***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
substr($StringB, 0, strlen($StringA)) == $StringA
```

Comment: I like this solution because it also works for empty strings (unlike `strpos($stringB, $stringA) === 0`).  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In PHP there is no StartsWith() like in other languages. As an alternative, you can use [`mb_strpos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php):

```
if(mb_strpos($source, $start) === 0)
```

You can create your own StartsWith() function:

```
function StartsWith($source, $start)
{
    return (mb_strpos($source, $start) === 0);
}
```

I strongly recommend using the [Multibyte String Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php). This way you can work with Unicode strings long before the year 2025 when PHP has full Unicode support ;-).

Comment: agreed we should all be using multi-byte

Comment: It doesn't make a difference in this case, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

how about using strpos? (http://php.net/strpos)

```
if (strpos($stringB, $stringA) === 0) {
    // matched
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
strcmp() / strcasecmp()
```

It takes into account if lengths are different and only compares until min length.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php

or:

```
substr_compare()
```

If you need to compare if StringB starts with StringA and to be certain it's not the other way arround (where StringB would be the shorter one).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-compare.php

Both of the above functions are fast and they only iterate through the shortest string once.

---

As opposed to:

```
strpos()
```

Which would attempt to find StringA *anywhere* in StringB, in order to return the position at which StringA starts.

```
preg_match
```

Or other regular expressions which are more expensive operations and should be used for situations where many things need to be checked

Regex engines need to compile the regex string and they employ a lot of backtracking and a lot of looping over the strings to find their matches.

Comment: +1 you are right sir :) also for reasons stated in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pos = strpos($StringB, $StringA)
```

If $pos is 1 or 0 (I forget which) then you know string B starts with string A.

EDIT: It is position 0.

Answer (score 1):

use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php) for that...

```
if(strpos($stringB, $stringA) === 0) {
    // starts with stringA
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer has already been accepted, but the following method is - unfortunately due to the nature of php - the only correct one: use `strncmp()` or `===`. Here's why:

Consider the following example input (both strings are equal except for the last number):

```
$StringA = '9223372036854775808';
$StringB = '9223372036854775807';
```

Now, we take the following solution:

```
var_dump(substr($StringB, 0, strlen($StringA)) == $StringA);
```

Can you guess the return value? It's:

```
true
```

Wait, what, why?! Here's why: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54547

PHP normally gets most of its data from external strings, even if they're numbers. So if your code reads `$_POST['key'] == 123` and `$_POST['key']` is actually `'123'`, it will still work because PHP will perform a type cast on the string to integer before it calculates the equality.

Same goes for `$_GET['key'] == $_POST['key']`, assuming both strings have numbers in them. And herein lies the kicker:

> PHP determines whether the string(s) look numeric first before
>   comparison. If the numeric value gets too big, however, they overflow
>   into a `double` and thus lose precision; this causes the comparison to
>   return an unexpected result.

Instead, to compare strings you have to very explicit:

```
// use strncmp() - the === here is not really necessary btw
var_dump(0 === strncmp($StringB, $StringA, strlen($StringA)));
// use === to perform the comparison in a strict manner
var_dump(substr($StringB, 0, strlen($StringA)) === $StringA);
```

Returns:

```
false
false
```

Normality restored :)

Comment: It's true but it's a particularity on typecasting. Not "the general case".

Comment: @MihaiStancu It's a good enough reason to always use `===` for string comparisons at the very least ;-)

Comment: Also when the strings contain letters after the numbers, their strlens would be longer so "999999999999999999998x" "999999999999999999999y" would be compared correctly even with the double equal sign.

Comment: @MihaiStancu that's because it fails the is_numeric test :)

Comment: Exactly, the extracted substring would be "long enough" to include the characters following the digits so it doesn't get cast as numeric. Which means that your observation is only useful when you are **knowingly** comparing double precision floats or large integers from SQL that you **know** you shouldn't convert to floats because you'd loose precision... in which case you should be using [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-cmp.php) anyway. :P

Comment: @MihaiStancu I have no idea what you mean by 'long enough'. You realize, though, that strings can contains only numerals even if they're not meant as numbers right? http://phpsadness.com/sad/47

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
if(preg_match('/^'.preg_quote($stringA).'.*/', $stringB){ do some stuff }
```

This will check if B starts with A regardless of string sizes.

EDIT: A good point was brought up. If you want to use preg_match on a string that may have regex special characters in it, use preg_quote($string) to make sure those are escaped before using the string in the regex.

Comment: Not only is it unnecessary overkill, $stringA may contain unescaped metacharacters, causing the test to fail when it shouldn't (for example, if $stringA begins with a $ it will always fail).

Comment: You'd need to pass `$stringA` to [preg_quote](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php). But I think regex is overkill as Aretfact2 mentions.

Comment: @Artefact2 Good point. I made sure to edit my answer to use preg_quote in order to avoid the issue you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
if (strlen($b) < strlen($a)) {
   //does not match
}

$len = strlen($a);
if (substr($b, 1, $len) == $a) {
   //matches
}
```